# How does TextView's append() method call the replace() method of SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, textview, spannablestringbuilder

I have this custom `SpannableStringBuilder` class:

```
public class ExpressionBuilder extends SpannableStringBuilder{

    public ExpressionBuilder(CharSequence text){
         super(text);
    }

    @Override
    public SpannableStringBuilder replace(int start, int end, CharSequence tb, int tbstart,
                                      int tbend) {
        // do something...
    }

}
```

And an `Editable.Factory` needed to converts a `TextView` into an `Editable` required by the `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
private final Editable.Factory editableFactory = new Editable.Factory() {
    @Override
    public Editable newEditable(CharSequence source) {
        return new ExpressionBuilder(source);
    }
};
```

Then attach the `TextView` to the `Editable.Factory`:

```
myTextView.setEditableFactory(editableFactory);
```

What the above code does basically, is whenever a new string is appended to the `TextView`, the `replace()` method is called in the `ExpressionBuilder` and all its parameters are set. I don't understand how the `append()` method of the `TextView` calls the `replace()` method of the `SpannableStringBuilder` and how its parameters are set. I searched the documentation but I didn't find any explanation.
Any help, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Editable Inteface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Editable.java#78) you will see the following:

```
/**
 * Convenience for replace(length(), length(), text, 0, text.length())
 * @see #replace(int, int, CharSequence, int, int)
 */
public Editable append(CharSequence text);
/**
 * Convenience for replace(length(), length(), text, start, end)
 * @see #replace(int, int, CharSequence, int, int)
 */
public Editable append(CharSequence text, int start, int end);
/**
 * Convenience for append(String.valueOf(text)).
 * @see #replace(int, int, CharSequence, int, int)
 */
public Editable append(char text);
```

So, it looks like calling `append()` on a *TextView* does result in a call to `replace()` under the hood.

If we take a closer look by executing the following code in the `onCreate()` method of an app

```
textView.append("123")
```

we can see that the following chain of calls is made:

[image]

Line 291 of the *SpannableStringBuilder* is in the `append()` method which reads:

```
// Documentation from interface
public SpannableStringBuilder append(CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
    int length = length();
    return replace(length, length, text, start, end);
}
```

Here we see that the a call to `append()` results in a call to `replace()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and for the effort.